# How can I preserve a files date/time stamp when uploading to Amazon s3?

Tags: amazon-s3

When ever we upload files to S3 (using a clinet like cloudberry), the files date changes to the upload date.  Is there a way to keep the current date/time?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot change the LastModified field. But you can add custom metadata (Amazon calls this "user metadata") to store the information: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html

You can store the date here and then retrieve it using the S3 API.

Comment: This is how e.g. `rclone` preserves local files when uploading them to S3 backends.